# Invalid command in address while starting the node1

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain

When I try to configure my node1 using geth in vs code it's showing invalid command in the address. I have mentioned the signer address as well as node1 address clearly. Then also i am getting this error

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Please, provide more details about the issue: command line used, configuration file, etc.